# Check if section in Site Prism has class of specific type

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, site-prism

Using Capybara in ruby and creating page objects with Site Prism. 
Http element looks like this:

```
<section class='service-widget'  id='service_id>
   <div class='title'> ... </div>
   <div class='content> ... </div>
</section>
```

I have created class for this section:

```
class ServicesSection < SitePrism::Section
end
```

and then added section to the page object:

```
class ServicesPage < SitePrism::Page
    sections :services, ServicesSection, 'section[id^="service_"]'
end
```

This element can be collapsed and only thing that indicates state of it(if it is collapsed or not) is it's class name which is changed from

```
<section class='service-widget'  id='service_id>
```

to

```
<section class='service-widget is-closed'  id='service_id>
```

How to find out that this element is collapsed(closed) or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your self-answer of `root_element[:class].include? 'is-closed'` will probably work just fine for your case, but isn't robust since it would also match an element with a class of `is-closed-tomorrow`. A more robust solution would be the following:

```
root_element.matches_css?('.is-closed', wait: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside ServiceSection I defined method:

```
def closed?
   root_element[:class].include? 'is-closed'
end
```

This returns true if 'is-closed' is part of class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `root_element` - that wasn't in the SitePrism README ;)